# How can I debug my Angular 2 project using VS Code and Opera browser?

Tags: angular, debugging, visual-studio-code, chromium, vscode-debugger

I want to debug Angular 2 using Visual Studio Code and Opera browser that's based on Chromium. There is a "Debugger for Chrome" extension and works. But how Can I config VS Code to use Opera instead? Is this possible?

This is my launch.json right now:

```js
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
   {
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm not a VS user, but you can launch a specific command line program such as Opera and pass the URL as a parameter. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations